# Starling TouchPhase.ENDED triggered too early

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

I am using starling framework.In this game player can touch and hold on the screen to ascend the protagonist in the air and when he releases the touch the protagonist starts falling (Similar to jetpack joyride).

Below is the code i have in the game class

```
private var touch:Touch;
private function onTouch(e:TouchEvent)
{
      touch = e.getTouch(this,TouchPhase.BEGAN);
      if (touch)
      {
          isAscending = true;
      }
      touch = e.getTouch(this,TouchPhase.ENDED);
      if (touch)
      {
          isAscending = false;
      }
}
```

When i test it on the device. It looks likes the variable **isAscending** turns **false** before releasing the finger from screen it only ascends for approx. 2 seconds.

What should i do ?I want it to ascend until the finger is relesed from screen or it reaches the maximum height.

Comment: are you sure this is where `isAscending` is set to false? have you added a `trace()` to verify?

Comment: @divillysausages I ran it again and now it is running fine . I don't know why that happened